# Made a table but it is missing the right border? Written code is attached

Tags: tables

I tried making this table, however, it is missing the right border.
This is the code I wrote to do so:

```
\begin{center}

 \begin{tabular}{||c c|c c c c c c c ||}

 \hline

 p & q & p & $\vee$ & [$\neg$ & (p & $\wedge$ & q)]\\ [0.5ex]

 \hline\hline

 T & T & T & T & F & T & T & T\\ 

 \hline

 T & F & T & T & T & T & F & F\\

 \hline

 F & T & F & T & T & F & F & T\\

 \hline

 F & F & F & T & T & F & F & F\\

 \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{center}
```

And this is what the output looks like:
[image]

Comment: you have specified the `||` to come after the 9th column but all your rows have 8 columns

Comment: Not intentionally, but your  right border is fine as is. The  wrong one are is the left border  (and the top and the bottom).  Consider the use `booktabs` package.

Comment: @Richard has your query been resolved by the answer below -- if so please accept the answer by ticking the green check mark on the right side of the answer-- if you found the answer helpful please upvote the answer by clicking on the upward pointing triangle on the right side of the answer

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Table with prettifying -- header row gray color

```
\rowcolor{gray!30}
```

entry in `T` highlighted--

```
 \makeatletter
\newcommand*{\minuscellcolor}{}
\def\minuscellcolor\ignorespaces{%
  % \ignorespaces not really needed, because \@ifnextchar gobbles spaces
  \@ifnextchar{T}{\cellcolor{green!40}}{}%
}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\minuscellcolor}c}
\makeatother
```

extra row space--

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
```

### The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}% note the table option
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\minuscellcolor}{}
\def\minuscellcolor\ignorespaces{%
  % \ignorespaces not really needed, because \@ifnextchar gobbles spaces
  \@ifnextchar{T}{\cellcolor{green!40}}{}%
}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\minuscellcolor}c}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

 \begin{tabular}{*{8}C}                    \toprule\rowcolor{gray!30}
 p & q & p & $\vee$ & [$\neg$ & (p & $\wedge$ & q)]      \\ 
 T & T & T & T & F & T & T & T                           \\ 
 T & F & T & T & T & T & F & F                           \\
 F & T & F & T & T & F & F & T                           \\
 F & F & F & T & T & F & F & F                           \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

### OR

Normal table

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}% note the table option
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{center}

 \begin{tabular}{*{8}c}                    \toprule
 p & q & p & $\vee$ & [$\neg$ & (p & $\wedge$ & q)]      \\ \hline \hline  
 T & T & T & T & F & T & T & T                           \\ \hline 
 T & F & T & T & T & T & F & F                           \\ \hline 
 F & T & F & T & T & F & F & T                           \\ \hline 
 F & F & F & T & T & F & F & F                           \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A c is too much the Table is expecting 9 coloumns but you are filling only 8. The table Either you fill you 9th coloumn or you remove a c.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{||c c|c c c c c c c ||}

 \hline
 p & q & p & $\vee$ & [$\neg$ & (p & $\wedge$ & q)]\\ [0.5ex]
 \hline\hline
 T & T & T & T & F & T & T & T\\ 
 \hline
 T & F & T & T & T & T & F & F\\
 \hline
 F & T & F & T & T & F & F & T\\
 \hline
 F & F & F & T & T & F & F & F\\
 \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

[image]